# Intellij doesn't display some of my logs in the debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, logcat

All of my log statements appear in `adb logcat`, but two of them don't appear in Intellij Logcat. Why?

```
    Log.i(TAG, "in the long click");
    CommentViewHolder commentViewHolder = (CommentViewHolder) view.getTag();
    Log.i(TAG, "got the comment holder");
    addRequest(mAppController.deleteComment(mPostId,
            commentViewHolder.comment_id));
    Log.i(TAG, "added the request");
    return true;
```

This is the output in the Intellij Logcat using the "All messages" filter:

```
05-22 20:14:30.723: INFO/rose_tag(24319): in the long click
```

This is the output using `adb logcat`:

```
I/rose_tag(24319): in the long click
I/rose_tag(24319): got the comment holder
I/rose_tag(24319): added the request
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. If you have a reproducible test case, please [report in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Thanks, I've reported it.